# How to recover old emails in a Thunderbird local folder

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

All of this is on Windows 10, with Thunderbird 91.5.1.

So, I was cleaning up an IMAP account that has a pretty low quota, and I selected a large number of emails and dragged them to my local folder. They disappeared from my IMAP account... but to my surprise, they don't show up in my local folder.

Just to make sure, I create a new local folder from scratch, drag some emails to it and look again. The new local folder is empty. I look at the disk file and it does definitely exist. I open it with a text editor and at least *some* of my mails seem to be there.

I use the "Repair folder" option several times, with no effect. Just as an experiment, I try exiting Thunderbird, backing up the folder files and then try to "compact folder" in Thunderbird again. Sure enough, the folder file gets emptied.

At last I  realized what **could** be going on. The local folders all had the option "Delete messages older than 15 days", and all the emails I had copied were older than that. I changed it to "Do not delete any messages"... but after that, I still cannot recover the mails that I had copied. The mails are there, since I can see them in the disk file, but there's no way for Thunderbird to show them again. Deleting the .msf files doesn't work.

What can I do?

Comment: The first thing I'd do is make a complete disk image, lest any further operations destroy the data. *Then* you can try to use third-party tools to salvage (undelete) mail in C:\Users\<usernm>\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\<profilenm>\Mail and C:\Users\<usernm>\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\<profilenm>\Imapmail (Windows location).

Comment: Okay. What third party tools?

Comment: Check the message headers. Each message should have an `X-Mozilla-Status` header entry. A status of `0001` means message exists. `0009` means deleted. I never tried to change this value, so I don't know if you can change it and undelete your messages this way.

Comment: @Robert Well, that one worked. At least it allowed me to recover *some* messages, from after I ran "Compact folder" for the last time.